# indentation error on If Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

```
if mssge <= answr:
    print("Too High, Try Again")
elif mssge >= answr:
    print("Too Low, Try Again")
else:
    print("Nice Job! R to play again; Q to quit")

    if event.type == pygame.Q:
            sys.exit()

    else event.type == pygame.R:
            break
            gotoline(7)
```

I have been making games for a while but I just started on python. I'm making a number guessing game out of boredom but I keep getting an Indentation Error on line 17, or the last else of the if statement.

Comment: BTW, the code block starting with `if event.type` is indented too much: it should be indented the same as the `print` call. And of course the `else event.type == pygame.R` should be `elif event.type == pygame.R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `else` clause doesn't take a condition. You could either write it as an `elif` clause, or as a straight-forward `else.` Note, BTW, that you should remove the `=` from the first two conditions to make the code correct:

```
if message_1 < rand_numb:
    # <= replaced with < in this condition ^
    print("Too High, Try Again")
elif message_1 > rand_numb:
    print("Too Low, Try Again")
    # >= replaced with > in this condition ^
else:
    # No condition on else ^
    print("Nice Job! R to play again; Q to quit")
```

Comment: Look at the line of the IndentationError. It's way below the else, because it's an other problem.

Comment: File "number_game.py", line 17
    else
       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have conditions in the `else`-statement.  `Else` is supposed to catch every case which is **not** caught by the preceding `if/elifs`.

Your first code-block should be

```
if message_1 <= rand_numb:
    print("Too High, Try Again")
elif message_1 >= rand_numb:
    print("Too Low, Try Again")
else:  # <------ no conditions here!
    print("Nice Job! R to play again; Q to quit")

if event.type == pygame.Q:
    sys.exit()

else event.type == pygame.R:
    gotoline(5)
    break
```

Comment: Your updated answer is incorrect. Please see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803093/indentation-error-on-if-statement#comment64975319_38803093). It's a Good Idea to test answer code before posting it...